# Can someone show me how to use the watch position () function with getCurrentPosition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-maps

Below is the code I have used which finds the user's position.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
        me = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
        infoWindow.setPosition(me);
          infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
        },

    function(error) {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
    else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      }
      function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
      infoWindow.setPosition(me);
      infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                            'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                            'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
    }
```

I have tried to add in the watch position function below but it doesn't work, I am not sure how it works.

```
var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
  (position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
});

 function getLocationUpdate(){
            if(navigator.geolocation){
               // timeout at 60000 milliseconds (60 seconds)
               var options = {timeout:60000};
               geoLoc = navigator.geolocation;
               watchID = geoLoc.watchPosition(showLocation, errorHandler, options);
            }

            else{
               alert("Sorry, browser does not support geolocation!");
            }
```

If somebody could help me to watch the user's position on a map I would really appreciate it! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The [watchPosition()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition) method is used to register a handler function that will be called automatically each time the position of the device changes. You can also, optionally, specify an error handling callback function.

This method returns a watch ID value then can be used to unregister the handler by passing it to the `clearWatch()` method.

To obtain the user's current location, you can call the `getCurrentPosition()` method. This initiates an asynchronous request to detect the user's position, and queries the positioning hardware to get up-to-date information. When the position is determined, the defined callback function is executed. You can optionally provide a second callback function to be executed if an error occurs. A third, optional, parameter is an options object where you can set the maximum age of the position returned, the time to wait for a request, and if you want high accuracy for the position.

If the position data changes (either by device movement or if more accurate geo information arrives), you can set up a callback function that is called with that updated position information. This is done using the `watchPosition()` function, which has the same input parameters as `getCurrentPosition()`. The callback function is called multiple times, allowing the browser to either update your location as you move, or provide a more accurate location as different techniques are used to geolocate you. The error callback function, which is optional just as it is for `getCurrentPosition()`, can be called repeatedly.

For more information check this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation)

Check also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948952/watchposition-vs-getcurrentposition-w-settimeout).

Answer (score -1):

Setting up members to be at where they should.rje blue dot i had noticed was way off for whomever to come find me. Working on a update that is fixing the correct coding .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).